# How to change span tag value with variable value jquery

Tags: jquery

I wanna change value in span tag element with variable value jquery

I have code like below

```
<input type="file" name="pdffile" id="fileInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Browse" required>
<span id="pdf" style="display:none;"></span>
```

And I have jquery like this

```
$str = $("#fileInput").val();
$splt = $str.split(".");
$('#pdf').text('Your Extension is'.$splt[1]);
```

Why does it not work?

Comment: Use this code: $('#pdf').innerHTML('Your Extension is'.$splt[1]);

Comment: Do you mean the span should be automatically updated every time the input element is changed by the user? @elegent-user - `.innerHTML` is a property, not a function, but in any case it doesn't exist on jQuery objects.

Comment: You are concatenating javascript like it's php. At least that's my first impression. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @nnnnnn, .html is the correct method that I should have written. I missed. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#fileInput').change(function() {
        $str = $("#fileInput").val();
        $splt = $str.split(".");
        $('#pdf').html('Your Extension is ' + $splt[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#fileInput").change(function() {
  var qwe = $(this)[0].files;

  console.log(qwe[0].name.split('.').pop())// another option to get extension name
  $('#pdf').show().text('Your Extension is ' + qwe[0].name.slice(-3));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="pdffile" id="fileInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Browse" required>
<span id="pdf" style="display:none;"></span>
```

Try this way

Comment: Using slice(-3) will only retrieve the last three characters. This would cause issues with image formats like jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating your variable wrong. You need to add a + and put the dot within the parenthesis. Also the display: none hides the result from view.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8hahhf8b/3/)

**html**

```
<input type="file" name="pdffile" id="fileInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Browse" required>
<span id="pdf"></span>
```

**js/jQuery**

```
$("#fileInput").change(function(){
$str = $("#fileInput").val();
$splt = $str.split(".");
$('#pdf').text('Your Extension is .'+$splt[1]);
});
```

Comment: On the `click` event, the is no filename yet in the field... Or it is the previous filename.

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette Hence the post scriptum.

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette I wouldn't say wrong. The question doesn't specify when the function needs to be run. But I suppose it does makes the answer a bit clearer. So I changed it :).

Answer (score 0):

In case of a filename containing dots in the filename part, like `my.trip.pictures.jpg`...
I suggest using regular expression to be sure to catch **the last dot** and the extention.

```js
$("#fileInput").change(function() {
  
  var ext = $(this).val().match(/(.+)(\..+)/)[2];

  $('#pdf').show().text('Your Extension is ' + ext);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="pdffile" id="fileInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Browse" required>
<span id="pdf" style="display:none;"></span>
```